# jQuery: on click hide specific div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On this [website](https://einrichtungstool.rosental-nexxt.ch/) I am trying to hide some elements on click.

As you can see I have some objects on the left that can me dragged and dropped on the right and on click they are "hidden".

It happens that if I put the same element 2 times both are hidden. I just need that just the selected elements is hidden on click.

This is what i tried JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
//Counter
counter = 0;
//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper:'clone',
    containment: 'frame',

    //When first dragged
    stop:function(ev, ui) {
        var pos=$(ui.helper).offset();
        objName = "#clonediv"+counter
        $(objName).css({"left":pos.left,"top":pos.top});
        $(objName).removeClass("drag");


        //When an existiung object is dragged
        $(objName).draggable({
            containment: 'parent',
            stop:function(ev, ui) {
                var pos=$(ui.helper).offset();
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                              console.log(pos.left)
                console.log(pos.top)
            }
        });
    }
});
//Make element droppable
$("#frame").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1){
            counter++;
            var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
            element.addClass("tempclass");
            $(this).append(element);
            $(".tempclass").attr("id","clonediv"+counter);
            $("#clonediv"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");

            //Get the dynamically item id
            draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
            itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
            console.log(itemDragged)

            $("#clonediv"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
        }
$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$(".dragged1").addClass("deleted-1");
$(".deleted-1").click(function(){
  $(".dragged1").hide();
});
$(".dragged2").addClass("deleted-2");
$(".deleted-2").click(function(){
  $(".dragged2").hide();
});
$(".dragged3").addClass("deleted-3");
$(".deleted-3").click(function(){
  $(".dragged3").hide();
});
$(".dragged4").addClass("deleted-4");
$(".deleted-4").click(function(){
  $(".dragged4").hide();
});
$(".dragged5").addClass("deleted-5");
$(".deleted-5").click(function(){
  $(".dragged5").hide();
});
$(".dragged6").addClass("deleted-6");
$(".deleted-6").click(function(){
  $(".dragged6").hide();
});
$(".dragged7").addClass("deleted-7");
$(".deleted-7").click(function(){
  $(".dragged7").hide();
});
$(".dragged8").addClass("deleted-8");
$(".deleted-8").click(function(){
  $(".dragged8").hide();
});
    }
});
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="options">
        <div id="drag1" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag1 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_1" class="rotate"></div>
        <div id="drag2" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag2 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_2" class="rotate"></div>
        <div id="drag3" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag3 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_3" class="rotate"></div>
        <div id="drag4" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag4 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_4" class="rotate"></div>
        <div id="drag5" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag5 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_5" class="rotate"></div>
        <div id="drag6" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag6 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_6" class="rotate"></div>
    <div id="drag7" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag7 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_7" class="rotate"></div>
    <div id="drag8" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag8 -->
      <div id="rotate_btn_8" class="rotate"></div>
    </div><!-- end of options -->
    <div id="frame">
    <input id="undo" type="button">
    </div><!-- end of frame -->
</div><!-- end of wrapper -->
```

How can I hide just one div?

Comment: I don't understand the question...? And where are `.dragged1` and `.deleted-1` in your HTML??

Comment: @LinkinTED hi I edited my post, now you can see how do I applied the .dragged1 abd .deleted-1 classes

Comment: because you are using class to hide the div. why not get the id on click and then hide the div based on id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using

```
$(".deleted-4").click(function(){
  $(".dragged4").hide();
});
```

all `.dragged4` will be hidden.

I see in the code that one div has both `.deleted-x` and `.draggedx` class:

```
<div id="clonediv1" class="ui-draggable dragged3 deleted-3" style="left: 1050.5px; top: 153px;"></div>
```

So this should work:

```
$(".deleted-4").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Note that the element will be hidden, not removed!
If you want to remove the item from the DOM, rather use

```
$(".deleted-4").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

And to make it dynamic for all items:

```
$("[class^='deleted-']").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem and also I learned something new ;)

Comment: @V.Pepe You're welcome. If the answer suits you, please mark it as solution (using the v-mark on the left of it).